# Regex in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm looking for all occurrences for strings in a text but i don't understand why code dosen't work. In the text, there are 2 occurences.

The Text :

```
<div class="infosLigneDetail pointer" onclick="javascript:toggleForfait('1');">
                    Alexandre OUICHER - Forfait Free illimité à 19,99 euros - 0627505460                        <input
```

The search string :

```
Alexandre OUICHER - Forfait Free illimité à 19,99 euros - 0627505460
```

The regex :

```
NSRegularExpression *regexpComptes = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=javascript:toggleForfait('[0-9]');\">).*?(?=<input)" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch error:NULL];
NSArray *matchesComptes = [regexpComptes matchesInString:content
                                                   options:0
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length])];
```

Do you know where is the problem ?

Comment: There is no error. String is not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't escape the `(` and `)` in `toggleForfait('[0-9]')`.  It's being treated as a capture group.  It should be `\(` and `\)` respectively... `toggleForfait\('[0-9]'\)`

The regex you want is `(?<=javascript:toggleForfait\('[0-9]'\);\">).*?(?=<input)` with the dotall option enabled **NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators**

Look here: http://regexr.com?30ool

Comment: thank you. Thank you too for link to regexr.com. I know the tools in air but not the link.

Comment: Thanks for the dotall enum value of NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators.